# Creating a table with a bargraph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a table in R that includes two values and a corresponding bargraph. I am trying to create a table that has the % voting democratic and the % voting Republican as well as a barplot of the vote margin (preferably colored red/blue depending on the direction of the margin) and I want to repeat this over 3 years (2018-2022 election years) for both men and women. I saw a graph like this from pew that I am trying to recreate [Image I am trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoINC.png).

The problems I am having are 1) that table packages like formattable or DT or gt do not let me have multiple layers to a table. So the year is always included in the table instead of acting like a facet would in ggplot. 2) I can't get the color of margin to be conditional on the direction of the vote choice. 3) I would like to use colors beyond base R i.e. blue2 and red3 or a hex code but the code I have only works with blue/red.

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
library(DT)

# data manipulation
table_example <- dat2 %>%
  mutate(
    gender2 = factor(ifelse(gender == 1, "Men",
                            ifelse(gender == 2, "Women", NA)),
                     levels = c("Women", "Men"))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(rvweight_post)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(gender2)) %>%
  filter(vv_turnout_gvm < 2 & (voted_rep %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10))) %>%
  filter(year %in% 2018:2022) %>%
  group_by(gender2, year) %>%
  summarize(
    demvote = round(weighted.mean(housevote == 1, rvweight_post, na.rm = TRUE) * 100),
    repvote = round(weighted.mean(housevote == 0, rvweight_post, na.rm = TRUE) * 100),
    margins = round(demvote - repvote)
  ) 

# code to create that table without dat2
data <- data.frame(
  gender = c("Women", "Women", "Women", "Men", "Men", "Men"),
  year = c(2018, 2020, 2022, 2018, 2020, 2022),
  demvote = c(58, 55, 52, 49, 47, 43),
  repvote = c(41, 44, 47, 50, 52, 55),
  margins = c(17, 11, 5, -1, -5, -12),
  voted_rep = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
)

# Formattable 
ft <- formattable(
  table_example,
  list(
    demvote = color_bar("blue", proportion),
    repvote = color_bar("red", proportion),
    margins = color_bar(ifelse(res$margins > 0, "blue", "red"))))
```

Suffers from problems 1 and 3

```
`# DT table
datatable(table_example, options = list(
  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(3, 4, 5)))
)) %>%
  formatStyle(c("demvote"),
              background = styleColorBar(c(dat2_summary$demvote), "blue", -90), backgroundPosition =  "right") %>%
  formatStyle(c("repvote"),
              background = styleColorBar(c(dat2_summary$repvote), "red", -90), backgroundPosition =  "right")
```

Suffers from problems 1, 2, and 3 as well as an additional problem that 2 of the numbers in the table aren't colored at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `ggplot2` approach to get you close to the image you referenced in your post which makes heavy use of `ggh4x`, especially `facet_nested` and `facetted_pos_scales`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

table_example_long <- table_example |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(gender, year),
    names_to = "stat"
  ) |>
  filter(stat != "voted_rep") |>
  mutate(
    facet = if_else(
      stat %in% c("demvote", "repvote"),
      "vote",
      "margin"
    ),
    facet = factor(facet, c("vote", "margin"))
  )


dat_segment <- table_example_long |>
  filter(stat %in% c("margins")) |>
  distinct(gender, facet, year) |>
  mutate(
    gender_num = as.numeric(factor(gender)),
    y = gender_num - .2,
    yend = gender_num + .2,
    stat = "margins"
  )

.dem <- "#0015BC"
.rep <- "#FF0000"
.grey <- "grey30"
.bg <- "#EFF0E3"
.font <- "sans"

texts <- c(
  replicate(3, ggtext::element_markdown(
    face = "bold", size = 12
  ), simplify = FALSE),
  replicate(6, NULL, simplify = FALSE),
  replicate(9, ggtext::element_markdown(),
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)

el_bg <- element_rect(
  fill = .bg,
  linewidth = 0
)
backgrounds <- c(
  list(NULL, NULL, el_bg),
  replicate(4, NULL, simplify = FALSE),
  replicate(2, el_bg, simplify = FALSE),
  replicate(6, NULL, simplify = FALSE),
  replicate(3, el_bg, simplify = FALSE)
)

ggplot(table_example_long) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, .5)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = data.frame(
      year = c(2022),
      facet = factor(c("vote", "vote", "margin"), c("vote", "margin")),
      stat = c("demvote", "repvote", "margins")
    ),
    aes(
      xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
      ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
    ),
    fill = .bg
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = Inf,
    color = .grey
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    yintercept = c(1.5, .5),
    color = .grey,
    linetype = "dotted"
  ) +
  geom_vline(
    data = data.frame(
      year = c(2018, 2020),
      facet = factor("margin", c("vote", "margin")),
      stat = "margins",
      xintercept = Inf
    ),
    aes(xintercept = xintercept),
    color = .grey
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = dat_segment,
    aes(
      x = 0, xend = 0,
      y = y, yend = yend
    )
  ) +
  geom_col(
    data = ~ subset(.x, stat %in% c("margins")),
    aes(x = value, y = gender, fill = value > 0),
    orientation = "y",
    width = .3
  ) +
  geom_label(
    data = ~ subset(.x, stat %in% c("margins")),
    aes(
      x = value, y = gender,
      label = scales::number(value, style_positive = "plus"),
      hjust = if_else(value > 0, 0, 1)
    ),
    family = .font,
    fill = NA,
    label.size = 0,
    color = .grey
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = ~ subset(.x, stat %in% c("demvote", "repvote")),
    aes(x = stat, y = gender, label = value, color = stat),
    family = .font
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(
      demvote = .dem, repvote = .rep,
      "TRUE" = .dem, "FALSE" = .rep
    ),
    aesthetics = c("color", "fill")
  ) +
  facet_nested(
    ~ year + facet + stat,
    scales = "free_x",
    space = "free_x",
    labeller = labeller(
      facet = c(
        vote = "SHARE\nVOTING ...",
        margin = "VOTE\nMARGINS"
      ),
      stat = c(
        margins = paste0(
          "<span style='color: \"", .grey, "\"'>(DEM-REP)</span>"
        ),
        demvote = paste0(
          "<span style='color: \"", .dem, "\"'>Dem</span>"
        ),
        repvote = paste0(
          "<span style='color: \"", .rep, "\"'>Rep</span>"
        )
      )
    ),
    strip = strip_nested(
      text_x = texts,
      background_x = backgrounds
    )
  ) +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    x = list(
      facet == "margin" ~ scale_x_continuous(
        limits = range(table_example$margins),
        position = "top",
        expand = c(0, 5, 0, 10)
      ),
      facet == "vote" ~ scale_x_discrete(
        position = "top",
        expand = c(0, 5)
      )
    )
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_minimal(base_family = .font, base_size = 14) +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x.top = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x.top = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length.x.top = unit(0, "pt"),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    strip.text.x.top = element_text(
      color = .grey
    )
  ) +
  guides(fill = "none", color = "none") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)

ggsave(
  "table.png",
  width = 900,
  height = 225,
  units = "px",
  scale = 300 / 96,
  bg = "white"
)
```

[image]